Given a dataframe with timestamp as index and 2 columns with IDs and boolean values, get a new dataframe with transitioned bool for each ID
I have a pandas dataframe with two columns and an index which is a datettime object, the first column is an ID and the second column is a boolean value, for a given ID the boolean column can be True or False for multiple rows and transitions back and forth over the length of the dataframe, I want to get the first row for a transitioned boolean value for each ID, how do I do that?
Example:
TS      ID  Val
8:00:12 X   TRUE
8:00:50 X   TRUE
8:01:23 Y   FALSE
8:03:45 X   FALSE
8:05:01 Z   TRUE
8:05:29 Z   TRUE
8:06:13 Z   FALSE
8:07:05 Y   FALSE

Should give:
TS      ID  Val
8:00:12 X   TRUE
8:01:23 Y   FALSE
8:03:45 X   FALSE
8:05:01 Z   TRUE
8:06:13 Z   FALSE

Different IDs can be in different TRUE/FALSE states through out the time series but I just want to get the first transitioned row in each case, if that makes sense?
To clarify, using this code:
cols = ['symbol','onRunUp']
result = df[df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1)].iloc[:-1]
result

On the following data:
        ID  Val
TS      
8:00:12 X   FALSE
8:00:50 X   FALSE
8:01:23 Y   TRUE
8:03:45 X   FALSE
8:05:01 X   FALSE
8:05:29 Z   FALSE
8:06:13 Z   FALSE
8:07:05 Z   FALSE
8:10:36 Z   FALSE
8:10:40 Z   FALSE
8:11:01 Z   FALSE
8:11:42 X   FALSE
8:11:58 X   FALSE
8:12:30 X   FALSE
8:12:43 X   FALSE

I get the following:
        ID  Val
TS      
8:00:12 X   FALSE
8:01:23 Y   TRUE
8:03:45 X   FALSE
8:05:29 Z   FALSE

But the desired output should be:
        ID  Val
TS      
8:00:12 X   FALSE
8:01:23 Y   TRUE
8:05:29 Z   FALSE

because X has not changed value
To summarise, in the resulting dataframe I should see:

A row for the first ID/Val pair seen
A row for every subsequent transition from the previously seen Val for each ID, ie every time ID:X changes from True to False, I should see a row with the timestamp that it became False and vice a versa.

For a given ID, I shouldn't see consecutive rows for that ID with the same Val in the resulting datafame.
Hope this colour helps! Thanks again!

Can you double check your output?

Why is first Z=False ? It should be True

Apologies, yes updated. That's why I need code to do this! : )

Are you sure of the last row? Do you want to exclude the last row?

I believe you want to identify any change in either column, see the last two options in my answer and let me know

So need df.drop_duplicates(subset=['symbol','onRunUp']) ?

You can compare the successive IDs (with ne and shift) to identify the changes and aggregate with any to form the first mask, also compute a mask for the not already seen ids, then perform boolean indexing:
import numpy as np

# identify change in ID/Val
cols = ['ID', 'Val']
m1 = df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1)

# only keep the IDs that were not already seen
a = pd.factorize(df['ID'])[0]
m2 = a==np.maximum.accumulate(a)

out = df[m1&m2]

Output:
        ID    Val
TS               
8:00:12  X  False
8:01:23  Y   True
8:05:29  Z  False


I tried the above code but didn't get the result I'm looking for. I updated the question above with your code and more colour. Thanks @mozway

Then add drop_duplicates() in the end of my last answer. The iloc[:-1] is optional depending if you want to exclude the last row

Sorry, that's not it either because X may be True or False multiple times through out the time series and I need a row each time it transitions from True to False or False to True with the timestamp of the transitioned row for each ID. drop_duplicates() will drop any re-occurence of a previously seen Val.

@Demps why don't you take the time to break down the logic for each row in your example. Clearly explain in words why you keep it or not

Added a summary, does this clear things up?

@Demps I think so, please give the update a try and I'll add details afterwards

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Why don't you just use :df.groupby('ID').head(1)
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['8:00:12', 'X', False],
    ['8:00:50', 'X', False],
    ['8:01:23', 'Y', True],
    ['8:03:45', 'X', False],
    ['8:05:01', 'X', False],
    ['8:05:29', 'Z', False],
    ['8:06:13', 'Z', False],
    ['8:07:05', 'Z', False],
    ['8:10:36', 'Z', False],
    ['8:10:40', 'Z', False],
    ['8:11:01', 'Z', False],
    ['8:11:42', 'X', False],
    ['8:11:58', 'X', False],
    ['8:12:30', 'X', False],
    ['8:12:43', 'X', False]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['TS', 'ID', 'Val'])


# Identify the first occurrence of each unique 'ID'
first_occurrences = df.groupby('ID').head(1)

print(first_occurrences)
        TS ID    Val
0  8:00:12  X  False
2  8:01:23  Y   True
5  8:05:29  Z  False

If You want something like  :
        TS  ID    Val  change_mask
0   8:00:12  X  False         True  # Initial row, always True
2   8:01:23  Y   True         True  # Change in ID and Val from previous row
3   8:03:45  X  False         True  # Change in ID from previous row
5   8:05:29  Z  False         True  # Change in ID from previous row
11  8:11:42  X  False         True  # Change in ID from previous row

Then :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['8:00:12', 'X', False],
    ['8:00:50', 'X', False],
    ['8:01:23', 'Y', True],
    ['8:03:45', 'X', False],
    ['8:05:01', 'X', False],
    ['8:05:29', 'Z', False],
    ['8:06:13', 'Z', False],
    ['8:07:05', 'Z', False],
    ['8:10:36', 'Z', False],
    ['8:10:40', 'Z', False],
    ['8:11:01', 'Z', False],
    ['8:11:42', 'X', False],
    ['8:11:58', 'X', False],
    ['8:12:30', 'X', False],
    ['8:12:43', 'X', False]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['TS', 'ID', 'Val'])
#print(df)
"""
         TS ID    Val
0   8:00:12  X  False
1   8:00:50  X  False
2   8:01:23  Y   True
3   8:03:45  X  False
4   8:05:01  X  False
5   8:05:29  Z  False
6   8:06:13  Z  False
7   8:07:05  Z  False
8   8:10:36  Z  False
9   8:10:40  Z  False
10  8:11:01  Z  False
11  8:11:42  X  False
12  8:11:58  X  False
13  8:12:30  X  False
14  8:12:43  X  False
"""

# Convert ID to a numerical format using factorize
id_codes,id_uniques = pd.factorize(df['ID'])
print(id_codes)#[0 0 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0]
print(id_uniques)#Index(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='object')

# Create a boolean array to mark changes in 'ID' or 'Val'
change_mask = np.r_[True, np.any(np.diff(np.c_[id_codes, df['Val'].astype(int)], axis=0) != 0, axis=1)]
df['change_mask'] = change_mask
print(df)
"""
         TS ID    Val  change_mask
0   8:00:12  X  False         True
1   8:00:50  X  False        False
2   8:01:23  Y   True         True
3   8:03:45  X  False         True
4   8:05:01  X  False        False
5   8:05:29  Z  False         True
6   8:06:13  Z  False        False
7   8:07:05  Z  False        False
8   8:10:36  Z  False        False
9   8:10:40  Z  False        False
10  8:11:01  Z  False        False
11  8:11:42  X  False         True
12  8:11:58  X  False        False
13  8:12:30  X  False        False
14  8:12:43  X  False        False
"""
res = df[change_mask]
print(res)
"""
        TS ID    Val  change_mask
0   8:00:12  X  False         True
2   8:01:23  Y   True         True
3   8:03:45  X  False         True
5   8:05:29  Z  False         True
11  8:11:42  X  False         True
"""

Explanation :
# Combined ID codes and casted values for difference calculation
combined_data = np.c_[id_codes, df['Val'].astype(int)]

# Differences between consecutive rows denoted by axis=0 
row_differences = np.diff(combined_data, axis=0)

# Check for any difference in ID code or value between rows (axis=1)
#np.any(..., axis=1): This checks if there is any non-zero difference in each row (i.e., if any column in a row has changed).
has_changes = np.any(row_differences != 0, axis=1)

# Create change mask with True for rows having a change
change_mask = np.r_[True, has_changes]

If we want to Emphasize the rows where both the ID code changes and it's the first occurrence of that exact ID. Then,
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['8:00:12', 'X', False],
    ['8:00:50', 'X', False],
    ['8:01:23', 'Y', True],
    ['8:03:45', 'X', False],
    ['8:05:01', 'X', False],
    ['8:05:29', 'Z', False],
    ['8:06:13', 'Z', False],
    ['8:07:05', 'Z', False],
    ['8:10:36', 'Z', False],
    ['8:10:40', 'Z', False],
    ['8:11:01', 'Z', False],
    ['8:11:42', 'X', False],
    ['8:11:58', 'X', False],
    ['8:12:30', 'X', False],
    ['8:12:43', 'X', False]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['TS', 'ID', 'Val'])

id_codes,id_uniques = pd.factorize(df['ID'])
print(id_codes)#[0 0 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0]
"""
transitions array acts as a flag that tells you whether a particular row 
represents a transition point based on changes in ID code or value.
"""
transitions = np.zeros_like(id_codes,dtype= 'bool')
print(transitions)

transitions[1:] = np.diff(np.c_[id_codes,df['Val'].astype(int)] != 0 ,axis=0).any(axis=1)
df['transitions'] = transitions

first_occurrence = np.zeros_like(id_codes,bool)
first_occurrence[np.unique(id_codes,return_index = True)[1]] = True
df['first_occurrence'] = first_occurrence

print(df)
"""
        TS ID    Val  transitions  first_occurrence
0   8:00:12  X  False        False              True
1   8:00:50  X  False        False             False
2   8:01:23  Y   True         True              True
3   8:03:45  X  False         True             False
4   8:05:01  X  False        False             False
5   8:05:29  Z  False         True              True
6   8:06:13  Z  False        False             False
7   8:07:05  Z  False        False             False
8   8:10:36  Z  False        False             False
9   8:10:40  Z  False        False             False
10  8:11:01  Z  False        False             False
11  8:11:42  X  False         True             False
12  8:11:58  X  False        False             False
13  8:12:30  X  False        False             False
14  8:12:43  X  False        False             False
"""

mask = (first_occurrence & transitions)
res = df[mask]
print(res)
"""
        TS ID    Val  transitions  first_occurrence
2  8:01:23  Y   True         True              True
5  8:05:29  Z  False         True              True
"""


df.groupby('ID').head(1) can be replaced by df.drop_duplicates('ID') that is much more efficient. That said, the expected logic seems quite different although not fully clear.
